Playing m3u8 Link with token in AVPlayer with AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate
I'm trying to secure my m3u8 streaming link with a token.I am using flussonic cdn To achieve this, I'm using AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate in my SwiftUI app. However, the video is playing but when existing token is invalid and i update the token via resourceloader the player is paused for few seconds.
        if var urlComponents = URLComponents(url: redirectURL, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
        var queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []
        
        // Check if the token already exists
        if let existingTokenIndex = queryItems.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "token" }) {
            // Update the existing token
            queryItems[existingTokenIndex].value = token
        } else {
            // Add the token if it doesn't exist
            queryItems.append(URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: token))
        }
        
        urlComponents.queryItems = queryItems
        redirectURL = urlComponents.url!
    }

